# PHP - getting wrong JSON

Tags: php, android, mysql

I'm writing a `PHP` code for inserting the work order name in a spinner.
I need a `JSON` String called `success = 1` along with **JSON** Array.
I want to use that JSON string in the android spinner.
I'm getting only `JSON` array.
here is my code:

```
        <?PHP
require_once('connection.php');
$workName = "SELECT workorder_name FROM workorder_category";
$con=mysqli_connect($server_name,$user_name,$password,$db);
$r = mysqli_query($con,$workName);


$result = array();
$resultArr = array('success' => true);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r)){

        array_push($result,array('$workOrderName'=>$row['workorder_name']));
        }
echo json_encode(array('result'=>$result));
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

I want an output as like this:

```
{"success":1,result":[{"$workOrderName":"electrician"},{"$workOrderName":"plumber"},{"$workOrderName":"carpenter"}]}
```

currently, I am getting the output like

```
{
    "result": [
        {
            "$workOrderName": "electrician"
        },
        {
            "$workOrderName": "plumber"
        },
        {
            "$workOrderName": "carpenter"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: `$result = array();` ... `array($result)` you are putting your array inside another array. I suppose you wanted it to proof cast as an array, that would be `json_encode(array)$result);`

Comment: The $result is an array and the end of the code in the json_encode call, it puts again into an array. Remove it and it returns a json string not an array.

Comment: The row `array("success" => 1);` is a weird one. If you want it to be saved, you need to store it on some variable. Right now, it doesn't really do anything.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I changed the code as you said and I also edited the question by adding the required output. tell me what is wrong with the code.

Comment: You say _"I need a JSON String called success = 1"_ but your example output still shows differently. The example shows a json object with a parameter named "success", which contains an integer. Your update basically made your question more unclear.

Comment: If the example result is what you want, then my answer below will give you that. If that's _not_ what you want, then change the example.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating two arrays, one for the result and one for the success, define the structure in just one array and append to that:

```
// The main structure
$result = [
    'success' => 1,
    'result'  => [],
];

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r)){
    // Append to the sub key "result" (which we already defined as an array)
    $result['result'][] = ['$workOrderName'=>$row['workorder_name']]; 
}

// Just encode the complete array
echo json_encode($result);
```

**Note:** This example uses the short array syntax `[]` (introduced in PHP 5.4) instead of the long syntax: `array()`. They do the exact same thing.

I also changed `array_push()` to a shorter version: `$someArray[] =`.

Comment: sorry, What you did is correct. I want to know whether the success can be used as JSON string in android or not.

Comment: @Chandu - Nowhere in your question have you even mentioned that. The above will return what you gave as an example output. I don't really understand what else you're asking.

Comment: I have editted the question please respond @MagnusEriksson

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = array();
$resultArr['success'] =true;
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r))
{

        array_push($result,array('$workOrderName'=>$row['workorder_name']));
        }
$resultArr['result']  = $result;
echo json_encode($resultArr);
```

This will work fine.